# Convert tetrahedral mesh file into face-based file (*.obj, *.ply, etc.) for visualization

Tags: graphics, visualization, tetrahedra

In computer graphics, it's common to use `*.node` and `*.ele` files to store tetrahedral mesh, where the former one stores 3D coordinates `(x,y,z)` of all the vertices and the latter one stores the indices of every tetrahedron, such as

```
#<tetrahedron index> <vertex 1> <vertex 2> <vertex 3> <vertex 4> <attribute>
          1             1          2           3          4          1
         ...           ...        ...         ...        ...        ...
```

which means a tetrahedron with index 1 consists of vertices with indices 1, 2, 3, 4 and has attribute 1.

However, it is difficult to visualize such kinds of files. So are there any libraries which can convert such kinds of `*.node` and `*.ele` files into `*.obj` or `*.ply` files for visualization in MeshLab?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/): `tetgen -r my_node_file -O`. This should output a `my_node_file.off` file with a [format](http://www.geomview.org/docs/html/OFF.html) similar to PLY or OBJ files (the file can either be patched in a text editor to PLY or MeshLab can do the conversion). However I believe this works only with TetGen version <= 1.4 (in 1.5, the `-O` option has a different meaning).

That being said, it should also be trivial to write a custom parser that will generate a PLY or OBJ file (and you gain the flexibility of filtering by attributes or do some other processing on the faces of the tetrahedral mesh).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yet I am still a little confused about how to use the command. There are 2 files: `*.node` and `*.ele`, how can they be included in this command?

Comment: You either give the fullname of your `.node` file and the program will figure out what the corresponding `.ele` file is. Or you simply give the name of your `.node` / `.ele` files without the extension.